# cucumber cypress query > After configer with .feature file, why .js file not apper

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I have configured my package.json & cypress.json & index.js as per cucumber requirement refer this link < [https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor>](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor%3E)

file stucture C:\Users\Ankit\CypressAutomation\cypress\integration\2-advanced-examples\BDD\ecommerce\ecommercestepdef.js & for feature file C:\Users\Ankit\CypressAutomation\cypress\integration\2-advanced-examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature

I have getting error in this:- node_modules/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/resolveStepDefinition.js:199:1

Step implementation missing for: I open ecommerce page

[folder structure & feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiyGB.png)
[data from fixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcMOf.png)

[stepdeintion1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21gE.png)

[stepdefination2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkfH9.png)

[plugins>indexjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmDNU.png)

[packetjson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8yCA.png)

[cypressjson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo6lF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there's a blank space before the step definition 1, at line 12, that could cause preprocessor not to recognize the implementation of the sentence in the feature

[image]

Comment: Thanks yeah this is the error